# How to track mouse over on an item in an SWT combo box (hot tracking)

Tags: java, swt

I have a combo box which shows various items. I would like to change the tooltip text depending on the item under the mouse pointer. Since I cannot set a tooltip for each item, I need to change the tooltip for the combo box.

How do I get the item under the mouse pointer? I can set up an event for tracking mouse movement, and then get the Point for the mouse, however I cannot find a method to get the item in the combo matching the Point location.

A Tree has this:

```
private class KeyTreeMouseMoveListener implements MouseMoveListener
{
    @Override
    public void mouseMove( MouseEvent event )
    {
       TreeItem item = tree.getItem( new Point( event.x, event.y ) );
    }
}
```

But I cannot find a similar method for a Combo box.

Something like:

```
private class ComboMouseMoveListener implements MouseMoveListener
{
    @Override
    public void mouseMove( MouseEvent event )
    {
       int index = combo.getIndex( new Point( event.x, event.y ) );
    }
}
```

would be nice :-)

Comment: Since the combo uses a native control this probably isn't possible.

Comment: Yes, I kind of thought so.

Comment: And just to make it more interesting, the tooltip only shows when the combo box is "closed". If you click on the combo box and it expands, the tooltip is not shown.

Comment: This is also going to behave very differently on different platforms. The macOS combo is quite different from the Windows one. You could also look at `CCombo` which is mostly SWT code rather than native code.

Comment: Still the same behavior, The tootlip only shows if the combo box is closed. So even if I could hot track  the mouse and get the underlying item, the tooltip would not show

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it's kind of ugly, and kind of bad practice, so don't try this at home...

```
private class ComboModifyListener implements ModifyListener
{
    @Override
    public void modifyText( ModifyEvent e )
    {
      <code to get the selected item>
      combo.setToolTipText( "item tooltip text" );

      // ugly part
      ivShell.getDisplay().setCursorLocation(
        ivShell.getLocation().x + combo.getLocation().x + 15,
        ivShell.getLocation().y + combo.getLocation().y + 35 );
    }
}
```

So AFTER the user chooses an item, I get the item, set the combo tooltip, and then move the cursor so it is now over the combo box. The `x + 15` and `y + 35` are SWAG offsets from the top/left corner of the combo box.

Yes, I know its bad practice to move the cursor under program control, but it does display the tooltip of the selected item.

Comment: Ok, a little cleaner and the mouse just moves up: ```ivShell.getDisplay().setCursorLocation( ivShell.getDisplay().getCursorLocation().x, ivShell.getLocation().y + combo.getLocation().y + 35 );```